# How to update object with own properties only?

Tags: lodash

I'd like to update my object with new one (but only with own properties) using lodash. I was reading documentation, but could not find much (or just simply I don't get it). Any ideas?

```
let x = { name: 'John', last: 'Doe' };
let y = { age: 23 };
let z = { last: 'Smith', age: 25 };

_.something(x, y); // should be { name: 'John', last: 'Doe' };
_.something(x, z); // should be { name: 'John', last: 'Smith' };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.keys()` to get an array of the origin object keys, and use the array to `_.pick()` properties from the 2nd object. `_.assign()` the picked property to the object, or a new object `{}` if you don't won't to mutate the original.

```js
let x = { name: 'John', last: 'Doe' };
let y = { age: 23 };
let z = { last: 'Smith', age: 25 };

console.log(_.assign({}, x, _.pick(y, _.keys(x))));
console.log(_.assign({}, x, _.pick(z, _.keys(x))));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!